# Node-js SyntaxError running npm

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, node-modules

Whenever I run any 'npm' command, I get this error.

```
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

My node version

```
node -v
> v4.2.6
```

I believe the latest is 14, but I'm not able to update it either.

I've tried running

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
```

and then,

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
>Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Did `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -` succeed or did it fail?

Comment: Seems like it succeeded. At the end it says ## Run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 12.x and npm